# php error Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, joomla2.5, breezingforms

I have an admission form which is getting value from database table. Scenario is I have list of courses a student select a course and I pass course ID in URL then use this code to get corresponding Course name in the field: (The form is designed in joomla using breezing forms.)

```
$this->execPieceByName('ff_InitLib');
$course_id= JRequest::getVar('CID');
global $database, $rec;
$database->setQuery("SELECT * FROM course_list WHERE record = '$course_id' AND name = 'CourseName'");
$row = $database->loadObjectList();
$rec = $row[0];
ff_setValue('ProsCourse', $rec->value);
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

> *** EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FACILEFORMS ***
>   PHP error level : E_NOTICE
>   PHP filename : /home/web10385/public_html/********/components/com_breezingforms/facileforms.process.php(1219) : eval()'d code
>   PHP linenumber : 7
>   Last known pos : Before form custom piece code at line 1
>   Error message : Undefined offset: 0
>
> *** EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FACILEFORMS ***
>   PHP error level : E_NOTICE
>   PHP filename : /home/web10385/public_html/********/components/com_breezingforms/facileforms.process.php(1219) : eval()'d code
>   PHP linenumber : 8
>   Last known pos : Before form custom piece code at line 1
>   Error message : Trying to get property of non-object

The above code is the before form piece.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not constructing the database object....

**You have declared `$database` but you haven't initialized it with an object...That's the problem..It seems you have forgotten it.**

Since, before initializing it, it's a `non-object` type. And you have tried to use it two times, hence you got two errors.

```
    global $database, $rec;
               ^^ uninitialized....
        $database->setQuery("SELECT * FROM course_list WHERE record = '$course_id' AND 
              ^^ but you are using it here....

        $row = $database->loadObjectList(.....
                ^^ here....
```

From the information seen this is what may be the solution:

**EDIT:**

```
$database=JFactory::getDbo();
```

Comment: But this is joomla database is already initialised by joomla can u please be specific i am not a programmer

Comment: I mean `$database` variable...but you haven't initialized...if it is initialized by joomla why did you declare it again....either you are missing something or i'm....Please post your full code...but i'm kinda sure that's the reason....that's the meaning of the error you got

Comment: From what I see from your current code...`$database` is a new global variable.. and that is no where initialized and though you are using `setQuery` method on it...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have done:

In Form pieces > Before form add this script:

```
$this->execPieceByName('ff_InitLib');
$course_id= JRequest::getVar('CID');

//intialize BF utilities
$this->execPieceByName('ff_InitUtilities');
global $database, $rec;
$database = ff_select('SELECT * FROM course_list WHERE record = '.$course_id.' ');
$rec = $database[0];
```

Then add this to the VALUE field of the TEXT field (course name):

```
<?php global $rec; return $rec->name; ?>
```

That should do it.

Peace.